# Is there an alternative for to_field in django ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

Is there a direct alternative for tp_field (e.g. ForeignKey field) in ManyToManyFields without using through with another ForeignKey field?

### Example:

```py
class A(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(...)
```

```py
class B(models.Model):
    a= models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

I use my Model B in my REST Api and I want to have A.name displayed and not pk. Is there any way to make something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this in your `views.py`

```
obj = B.objects.filter(id=id) 
mydata = obj.a.objects.all()
```

and than you have to iterate it like normal object for example in your template

```
{% for i in mydata %}
{{ i.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

or if you don't have any `id` as argument than you can get first row  like this

```
obj = B.objects.first()
```

Comment: Is there no other way? Because this way I have to share my other models with the API, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: i don't know about other way if know i will let you know

Comment: check this post i think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/67961260/14457833