# In how many ways can I get ManyToMany field data using Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

Let's assume I have two models named **`A`** and **`B`**. In model **`B`**, I have a **`ManyToMany`** field for model **`A`**, so how many ways can I get data from model **`A`** using model **`B`**?:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

Comment: So you have a model *object* from the model `A`, and you want to retrieve the *related* `B` objects?

Comment: no from model `B` i want to get all data of model `A`

Comment: all data, or all *related* data?

Comment: means i can access all the fields which is in model `A`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two most straightforward ways is by accessing the `a` manager of the model object of `B`, so:

```
model_b_object.a.all()
```

another way to retrieve the related objects, is by filtering the `B` model, so:

```
A.objects.filter(b=model_b_object)
```

If you defined a *through* model, for example:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(...)

class B(models.Model):
    a= models.ManyToManyField(
        A
        through='C'
    )

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then you can also access this through:

```
A.models.objects.filter(c__b=model_b_object)
```

but this only will make the ORM call more complex, and less readable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there no other way?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari: not one that would result in horrible performance, and *ugly* code.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari: or as *the Zen of Python* says: *There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.*

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem, I have seen a lot of your answers and some of them have helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can get data from model `B` using model `A` as shown below:

```py
for obj in A.objects.all():
    print(obj.b_set.all())
```

And, the code above also works with `Middle` model defined between model `A` and model `B` and the results are the same:

```py
class A(models.Model):
        name= models.CharField(...)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A, through="Middle")

class Middle(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('a', 'b'))
```