# Django REST serializer return filtered manytomany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True,null=False,primary_key=True,blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)

class Attend(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    people = models.ManyToManyField(Person,related_name="attend",through='attendperson')
```

i want to return **Person** with only filter **Attend** (by *date* ) 

 for ex:

Person with id = 1  registered for these *attend* date =2021-06-15  and another
date = 2021-06-29 
i want to serilizer  *Person* with filtered upcoming *attend* 
Note:

```
p = Person.objects.filter(id=1)[0]
p.attend.filter(date__gte='2021-06-18')
serial = PersonSerializer(p).data
```

doesn't do the trick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In how many ways i can get ManyToMany field data using Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67961024/in-how-many-ways-i-can-get-manytomany-field-data-using-django-orm)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari this will return all related data , i want partial related objects  based on filter to serialize it

Comment: okay so you want all the data but you are getting only one ?

Comment: no i want  only one  but get all data

Comment: when access  **person.attend**   i want filtered data , not all data 
when try  **person.attend.filter(date__gte='2021-06-16')**  doesn't  effect **person.attend** when pass it to serializer

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
p = Person.objects.filter(id=1, attend__date__gte='2021-06-16').get()
```

This will give you the person object with `id=1` if it has `date__gte=2021-06-16`, otherwise you will get a `Person.DoesNotExist` exception

Comment: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'date' into field. Choices are: id, name, username

Comment: Edited to add `attend__date__gte`

Comment: still when serialize  **Person** object  return all attend  not *attend__date__gte='2021-06-16'*

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code you have?