# How can i get many to many relationship table data in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Course(models.Model):
    Credits = (
        ('1', '0.75'),
        ('2', '1'),
        ('3', '2'),
        ('4', '3'),
        ('5', '4'),
        ('6', '5'),
        ('7', '6'),
    )

    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="CSE-101", unique=True)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="C Language", unique=True)
    course_credit = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Credits, default='4')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_code


class Student(models.Model):
    std_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    std_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    std_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True)

    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.std_id
```

when i input data in Student table, database create a table student_course, i want to get this student_course data.

I want to get data each student how many course they registered and each course name. How can i get this data and show this data in webpage?

I'm a noob to python and Django so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In how many ways I can get ManyToMany field data using Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67961024/in-how-many-ways-i-can-get-manytomany-field-data-using-django-orm)

Comment: Sir that is not clear answer i could not understand that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`i want to get this student_course data`* -> to access related object from student table you can access like this `Student.course.all()`

---

*`I want to get data each student how many course they registered and each course name`* -> You can retrieve courses of each student by filtering **Student** object like this

```
student = Student.objects.get(std_id=_place_student_id_here_)
courses = student.course.all() # this will return all courses related to perticular student
```

---

### Update

If you want to get courses for all users you've to do like this

```
students = Student.objects.all()
for student in students:
    print(student.course.all()) # this will return all courses for this student
```

if you want to reder courses in template do like this

in you **views.py**

```
def myview(request):
    students = Student.objects.all()
    return render(request, "studentlist.html",{'students':students})
```

in your **studentlist.html**

```
{% for student in students %}
  <p>Student Name : {{student.std_name}}<p>
  <p>Courses : 
   {% for course in student.course.all %}
     <span>{{course.course_name}}</span>
   {% endfor %}
  </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i apply this but it show [AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'] why

Comment: Hello @AubdurRobAnik how you're getting user instance can you provide that

Comment: You've to use `.get()` while retriving courses for a single user. Check my code

Comment: in views.py first i define a function then in this function i write "data = Student.objects.all() " and "cdata = Student.course.all()" then pass this data and cdata in a html file

Comment: sir i want to send this course data in a html file, like my html file name is studentlist.html, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

hi if you want to get courser per student this code can help you:

```
from models import Student

my_student = Student.objects.get(std_id = {student id})
student_course = my_student.course
totoal_course = student_course.count()
name_of_courses = [course.name for course in student_course.all()]
```